# How to use FilenameFilter recursively?

Tags: java, file-io

In an interview i was asked to write a program using FilenameFilter to find the path of the abc.txt in  C: drive without using getAbsolutePath().

I was clueless as the accept() of FilenameFilter returns true/false. How can i use it recursively to find out the path? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: These two are separate points.  You don't need a FilenameFilter to meet the requirements.  How does the FilenameFilter factor into this?

Comment: The `filter` does not "search", it just tells if a given filename does match (or not) a condition.

Comment: It's not possible to do this usefully. A FilenameFilter is so wrong for this task that using it could only make the code more complicated.

Comment: @Boann I think the idea was to write a program to recursively list files `File` methods, and use the `File.listFiles` overload that uses a `FilenameFilter`. Otherwise it has no sense.

Comment: @SJuan76 That's the only explanation, but it's still an abysmal idea. Perhaps the correct interview answer was to tell the interviewer it was a stupid thing to do? getAbsolutePath resolves the relative pathname in a system-dependent way with tricky rules. I'm not sure it's even possible on Windows to determine the current directory of a particular drive without something like getAbsolutePath. Even if you can mimick those rules, listFiles and FilenameFilter won't help as they will only find files that exist, whereas getAbsolutePath does not require the file to exist.